# How to run testng factory with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am using eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) with the testng plugin (version 6.14.0.201802161500). I created a maven project to learn testng from tutorials. I want to run a testng factory method in Eclipse but there is no "testng" option in the run menu. How do I make it run the factory ?

**My code :**

```
package com.learn.classes;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//run with testng is present for this.
public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        System.out.println("Simple test Method");
    }
}

package com.learn.factory;

import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

import com.learn.classes.SimpleTest;

//run with testng is NOT present for this.
public class SimpleTestFactory {

    @Factory
    public Object[] factoryMethod() {
        return new Object [] {new SimpleTest(), new SimpleTest()};
    }

}
```

**SOLUTION :**
Create an xml suite for the above class or method and run that with testng.

Ex. myfactory.xml

```
<suite name="Factorty Methods" verbose="1">
    <test name="My factory method">
        <classes>
            <class name="factory.SimpleTestFactory" />
            <methods>
                <include name="factoryMethod" />
            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Do you have a `testng.xml`, how is it configured?

Comment: @try-catch-finally - No. Is it necessary to have that in order to run factory class methods ?

Comment: Nevermind, probably not. With the 6.11.0.201703011520 plugin it works in my Eclipse. Please add the plugin version to your question. You might up/down grade.

Comment: @try-catch-finally - I have TestNG 6.14.0.201802161500. Are you aware of any bugs which might cause the issue I face ? I'll try downgrade.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your config, or _even better_ the XML from the .settings folder. Please also add the version you've tested to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you see this behavior is because the TestNG eclipse plugin looks for any test methods (at-least one method annotated with `@Test` annotation) in a class before enabling that contextual option via right click.

In the case of a factory (like how your sample code for `SimpleTestFactory` looks like), there are no test methods. That is why it disables the `Run As > TestNG test` option.

So one of the alternatives for this is to basically create a suite xml file, add a reference to `SimpleTestFactory` and then run it via the suite file.

You could also file an issue on the [eclipse TestNG plugin github page](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse) and ask if this can be fixed.

Ideally speaking a `@Factory` annotated method could be regarded as a starting point as well. I don't know the feasibility of it though.

I do know that IntelliJ is able to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I raised an issue here https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/415

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - Is there something that needs to be done from my side to avail the bounty associated with this question ?