# Testng - Is it okay to have one data provider input per test method?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I understand that testng DataProviders are meant to provide multiple inputs/input arrays to test methods. But, is it ever okay to have only one input per test method ? Is that an anti-pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG does not have any recommendation in terms of how many data inputs are at the minimum needed if one were to use a `@DataProvider`.

But here's the general convention that users follow.

When its known in advance that a `@Test` method is going to be run with just one set of parameter values then you should try and use `@Parameters` annotation which receives inputs from the suite xml file via the `<parameters>` tag.

If its known in advance that a `@Test` method would need to run with more than one set of parameter values, then you should use a `@DataProvider`.

If its not known in advance as to whether there would be just one parameter value or more than one, then you can just go with `@DataProvider`.

The advantage that `@DataProvider` has over `@Parameters` is that, `@DataProvider` driven `@Test` methods dont have to be mandatorily driven via a suite xml. You can run them as individual tests as well.

But when a `@Test` method receives values via a `@Parameters` annotation, then it would need to be run via a suite xml only (ofc-course you can circumvent that by injecting parameters using a TestNG listener, but that's more of a workaround than a solution)

Comment: Thanks. Here is another testng question with 50 bounty. Could you please answer that also ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057860/how-to-run-testng-factory-with-eclipse

Comment: Done. Please check and accept if you are happy with the answer.